# Notation of Relations which are not functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I am a student in class 11, and have a minor doubt regarding the notation of relations that are not functions. Clarifying this query will surely help me a lot.

I know that a function is represented in the form $f(x)=x^2+2$, where $x$ represents an element part of the domain, and $f(x)$ represents its corresponding image. I was wondering if this notation can only be applied to functions or all relations in general? For example, can I represent a **square root relation** (not a function since it fails the vertical line test) in the form $g(x)=\pm\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: The locus of a variable point $P$ that is always moves at a fixed distance from an origin, for example a satellite orbiting the earth is $d=\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}$, or $x^2+y^2=d^2$. Note, that the circle also doesn't satisfy the vertical line test. 

So, you could have a formula(for a relation) that doesn't represent a function.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, but my question is whether I can represent a relation g in the form g(x)=Some polynomial of x, or is this notation exclusively for functions?

Comment: A polynomial corresponds to a true function, so there's no problem in that case.

Comment: Anyway, the short answer to your question is that function notation is exclusively for functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 2):

No, you should use function notation only for actual functions. Writing "$x=\pm a$" is informal shorthand for "$x=a$ or $x=-a$" (usually in a context where you're solving for $x$ and there are multiple solutions), but an expression like $\pm a$ doesn't make sense as the *definition* of something. It's much clearer to define your relation as $g=\{(x,y)\mid y^2=x^2\}$.

Comment: Okay, my example may have not made the most sense. However, my question is whether it is possible to represent a relation 'g' which is not a function using the notation g(x)=Some polynomial of x

Comment: It's possible if you clearly define what your notation means, but there's no standard notation like that that people will understand. Aside from informal shorthand like $\pm$, every expression should denote exactly one value.

Comment: In his answer, William Elliot is suggesting that you use sets. If we define the notation $R(\{x\})$ to be the *set* of $y$ values for which $x R y$, then you can define the relation $g$ by setting $g(\{x\})=\{x,-x\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be a relation on a set S.

The expression $f(x)$ means " the object that is related to $x\in S$  by relation $f$".

The use of a ***definite description*** " the so and so" presupposes that the object under discussion (1) exists (2) is unique.

So, such an expression requires  relation $f$ to be a function.